# Reconnect using AnyEvent::Handle and tcp_connect

Tags: perl, anyevent

I have a simple TCP server and client written using [`AnyEvent::Handle`](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent::Handle) leveraging `tcp_connect` and `tcp_server`. The client connects to the server and sends the string `Test Message` every 5 seconds.

This works without issue if the server is reachable, however, if the server is unavailable when the client launches, or becomes unavailable, the client script never tries to reconnect.

I'd like it to try and reconnect if the connection handle is not available (destroyed?). If unavailable, do things (print status message perhaps), but try and reconnect every 5 seconds would be the ideal outcome.

I'm not sure how to do that. I've pared down my client and server code to the following.

#### Client

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use AnyEvent;
use AnyEvent::Handle;
use AnyEvent::Socket;
use Compress::Zlib;

my @bulk;

# Start Timer
my $timer = AnyEvent->timer(
    after    => 5,
    interval => 5,
    cb       => sub {
        push( @bulk, "Test message" );
        flush( \@bulk );
        undef @bulk;
    } );

my $host = '127.0.0.1';
my $port = 9999;

my $conn_cv = AnyEvent->condvar;
my $conn_hdl;

$conn_hdl = AnyEvent::Handle->new(
    connect          => [$host, $port],
    keepalive        => 1,
    on_connect_error => sub {
        print "Could not connect: $_[1]\n";
        $conn_hdl->destroy;

        #$conn_cv->send;
    },
    on_error => sub {
        my ( $out_hdl, $fatal, $msg ) = @_;
        AE::log error => $msg;
        $conn_hdl->destroy;

        #$conn_cv->send;
    },
    on_read => sub {
        my ( $self ) = @_;
        $self->unshift_read(
            line => sub {
                my ( $hdl, $data ) = @_;
                print $data. "\n";
            } );
    } );

$conn_cv->recv;

# Flush array of events
sub flush {
    my ( $bulk ) = @_;
    return 0 if scalar @{$bulk} == 0;

    my $output = join( ",", @{$bulk} );
    $output = compress( $output );
    my $l = pack( "N", length( $output ) );
    $output = $l . $output;
    $conn_hdl->push_write( $output );
}
```

#### Server

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use AnyEvent;
use AnyEvent::Handle;
use AnyEvent::Socket;
use Compress::Zlib;

my %holding;

my $host = '127.0.0.1';
my $port = 9999;

my %connections;

# Start Timer
my $timer = AnyEvent->timer(
    after    => 5,
    interval => 5,
    cb       => sub {
        print "Number of connected hosts: ";
        print scalar keys %connections;
        print "\n";
        foreach my $k ( keys %connections ) {
            delete $connections{$k} if $connections{$k}->destroyed;
        }
    } );

my $server_cv = AnyEvent->condvar;
my $server    = tcp_server(
    $host, $port,
    sub {
        my ( $fh, $h, $p ) = @_;
        my $handle;

        $handle = AnyEvent::Handle->new(
            fh        => $fh,
            poll      => 'r',
            keepalive => 1,
            on_read   => sub {
                my ( $self ) = @_;

                # Get Length Header
                $self->unshift_read(
                    chunk => 4,
                    sub {
                        my $len = unpack( "N", $_[1] );

                        # Get Data
                        $self->unshift_read(
                            chunk => $len,
                            sub {
                                my $data = $_[1];
                                $data = uncompress( $data );
                                print $data. "\n";
                            } );
                    } );

            },
            on_eof => sub {
                my ( $hdl ) = @_;
                $hdl->destroy();
            },
            on_error => sub {
                my ( $hdl ) = @_;
                $hdl->destroy();
            },
        );

        $connections{ $h . ':' . $p } = $handle;    # keep it alive.
    } );

$server_cv->recv;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
package MyConnector;

use strict;
use warnings;

use AE               qw( );
use AnyEvent::Handle qw( );
use Scalar::Util     qw( );

sub new {
   my $class = shift;
   my %opts = @_;

   my $self = bless({}, $class);

   {
      Scalar::Util::weaken(my $self = $self);

      my $on_connect       = delete($opts{on_connect});
      my $on_connect_error = delete($opts{on_connect_error});

      my $tries    = delete($opts{tries})    ||  5;
      my $cooldown = delete($opts{cooldown}) || 15;

      $self->{_connect} = sub {
         $self->{_timer} = undef;

         $self->{_handle} = AnyEvent::Handle->new(
            %opts,

            on_connect => sub {
               my ($handle, $host, $port, $retry) = @_;

               $self->{handle} = $handle;
               delete @{$self}{qw( _connect _handle _timer )};

               $on_connect->($handle, $host, $port, $retry)
                  if $on_connect;
            },

            on_connect_error => sub {
               my ($handle, $message) = @_;

               if (!$tries--) {
                  $on_connect_error->($handle, $message)
                     if $on_connect_error;

                  delete @{$self}{qw( _connect _handle _timer )};

                  return;
               }

               # This will happen when this callback returns,
               # but that might not be for a while, so let's
               # do it now in case it saves resources.
               $handle->destroy();

               $self->{_timer} = AE::timer($cooldown, 0, $self->{_connect});
            },
         );
      };

      $self->{_connect}->();
   }

   return $self;
}

sub handle {
   my ($self) = @_;
   return $self->{handle};
}

1;
```

I'm pretty sure it's free of memory leaks (unlike your code). You'd use it as follows:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use AE          qw( );
use MyConnector qw( );

my $host = $ARGV[0] || 'www.stackoverflow.com';
my $port = $ARGV[1] || 80;

my $conn_cv = AE::cv();

my $connector = MyConnector->new(
   connect   => [ $host, $port ],
   keepalive => 1,

   on_connect => sub {
       print("Connected successfully\n");
       $conn_cv->send();
   },

   on_connect_error => sub {
       warn("Could not connect: $_[1]\n");
       $conn_cv->send();
   },

   # ...
);

$conn_cv->recv();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This technically works, but on_connect_error will result in a barrage of connection attempts until successful. This option isn't very network friendly and pegs the cpu churning through the while loop until the connection is reestablished. Adding sleeps or arbitrary counters here seems to go against the nature of event handling framework like AnyEvent. Specifically, I need it to be able to do other things even when the network is down, but at some interval attempt a reconnect. If connection is successful, continue as normal.

Comment: So just use a timer! And of course, the calls to AnyEvent::Handle should be moved into the callback, which complicate things. See update.

Comment: While I made my code work using a timer, your option is certainly more robust and easily reusable. I can't say I understand all of it (due to my experience level), but it certainly illuminates some topics I need to work on. You mention memory leaks, and I was curious what you meant. If it's the @bulk growing out of control I plan to handle that. Is that what you were referring to or am I missing something? Thanks again!

Comment: The callbacks of the object stored in `$conn_hdl` capture `$conn_hdl`, forming a reference cycle. I avoided the reference cycles though the use of reference weekening and using the `$_[0]` instead of `$conn_hdl`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ikegami, I figured I might want to track the connection status and use that in conjunction with another AnyEvent timer watcher to reconnect if the connection isn't established. This results in connection attempts every second if the connection status ($isConnected) is zero. Meanwhile, the events are queued up for when the connection is reestablished.

If there is a simpler way to accomplish this, I'm all ears, but for now I think this will solve the issue.

```
my @bulk;
my $host = '127.0.0.1';
my $port = 9999;
my $isConnected = 0;

my $conn_cv = AnyEvent->condvar;
my $conn_hdl;

# Flush Timer
my $timer = AnyEvent->timer(
    after => 5,
    interval => 5,
    cb => sub {
        push(@bulk,"Test message");
        if ($isConnected == 1) {
            flush(\@bulk);
            undef @bulk;
        }   
    }
);

# Reconnect Timer
my $reconn = AnyEvent->timer(
    after => 1,
    interval => 1,
    cb => sub {

        if ($isConnected == 0) {

            $conn_hdl = AnyEvent::Handle->new(
                connect => [$host, $port],
                keepalive => 1,
                on_connect => sub {
                    $isConnected = 1;
                },
                on_connect_error => sub {
                    warn "Could not connect: $_[1]\n";
                    $conn_hdl->destroy;
                    $isConnected = 0;       
                },
                on_error => sub {
                    my ($out_hdl, $fatal, $msg) = @_;
                    AE::log error => $msg;
                    $conn_hdl->destroy;
                    $isConnected = 0;
                },
                on_eof => sub {
                    warn "EOF\n";
                    $conn_hdl->destroy;
                    $isConnected = 0;
                },
                on_read => sub {
                    my ($self) = @_;
                        $self->unshift_read(line => sub {
                            my ($hdl,$data) = @_;
                            print $data."\n";
                    });
                }
            );  
        }
    }
);

$conn_cv->recv;
```